# Template For Inorder Transversal With Syntax Error Looking for ';"

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I created a template for an inorder transverse of a binary tree.  I get a syntax error in declaring the stack.  It expects a ';' but I do not see where I would put an ';'

I can get it to run with int type instead of T type. I wonder what I am doing wrong in the template.

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <stack> 
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void inOrderTraversal(Node<T>* root)
{
    stack<Node<T>*> s; // BUILD ERROR "UNEXPECTED IDENTTIFIER, EXPECTTED ';'
    Node<T>* curr = root;
    // Initially s.empty==true
    while (curr != NULL || s.empty() == false)
    {
        /* Reach the left most Node of the
           curr Node */
        while (curr != NULL)
        {
            /* place pointer to a tree node on
               the stack before traversing
              the node's left subtree */
            s.push(curr);
            curr = curr->left;
            // end of inner whitl
        }

        /* Current must be NULL at this point */
        curr = s.top();
        s.pop();
        // print 
        cout << curr->data << " ";

        /* we have visited the node and its
           left subtree.  Now, it's right
           subtree's turn */
        curr = curr->right;

    } /* end of while */
}


// function to create binary tree node on the heap
template <typename T>
Node<T>* newNodeOnHeap(T data) {
    Node* nodetoreturn = new Node; // make node on the heap
    nodetoreturn->value = data;
    nodetoreturn->left = nullptr;
    nodetoreturn->right = nullptr;
    return &nodetoreturn;
}

// function to delete binary tree node on the heap
template <typename T>
void deleteNodeOnHeap(T& node){
    delete node; // delete node
   
}


int main() {
    // make a binary tree on the heap
    int data = 10;
    Node<int>* root = newNodeOnHeap(data);
    root->left = newNodeOnHeap(5);
    root->right = newNodeOnHeap(20);
    root->left->left = newNodeOnHeap(3);
    root->left->right = newNodeOnHeap(7);
    root->right->right = newNodeOnHeap(30);


// In order transversal of binary tree

    inOrderTraversal(root);
  
}
```

This is the error
`stack<Node<T>*> s; // BUILD ERROR "UNEXPECTED IDENTIFIER, EXPECTED ';'`

This is the Node.h file

```
#define NODE_H_JAMES

template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    // constructor
    Node(T val)
    {
        this->value = val;
        left = right = nullptr;
    
    }

};
```

Comment: The name of the class is `std::stack`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that was it. Grrrr